# jboss 5.1 ssl client authentification

Tags: ssl, openssl, jboss5.x, keytool, authentication

I have a problem with the client authentication in Jboss 5.1 GA. What I try to do is, client authentication with self generated and self signed certificates. Therefore I have a keystore my.keystore and a truststore my.truststore. I use the Java keytool. To generate a certificate, I use the command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias test -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keystore /mirrored/certs/my.keystore
```

To export this certificate, I use the command:

```
keytool -export -alias test -keystore /mirrored/certs/my.keystore -rfc -file /mirrored/certs/test.cert
```

After exporting the certificate into a file, I import it into the truststore with the command:

```
keytool -import -alias test -file /mirrored/certs/test.cert -storetype JKS -keystore /mirrored/certs/my.truststore
```

As owner for the certificate I use localhost.

The Jboss 5.1 GA is configured as follows in the server.xml:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8765" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="true" 
       keystoreFile="/mirrored/certs/my.keystore"
       keystorePass="mypasswd" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       truststoreFile="/mirrored/certs/my.truststore"
       truststorePass="mypasswd"/>
```

To test this configuration and the certificate I use openssl. First I verified the certificate from above. The certifikate is OK says openssl. Then I call my application-server via openssl s_client, i do this lacally using the command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -CAfile test.cert -connect localhost:8765
```

After doing this, I get the following output:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -CAfile test.cert -connect 10.180.10.74:8765
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = DE, ST = Bremen, L = Bremen, O = Signalis, OU = localhost, CN = localhost
verify return:1
140477019141960:error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:1193:SSL alert number 42
140477019141960:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=DE/ST=Bremen/L=Bremen/O=Signalis/OU=localhost/CN=localhost
i:/C=DE/ST=Bremen/L=Bremen/O=Signalis/OU=localhost/CN=localhost
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICazCCAdSgAwIBAgIEVCE7CTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB6MQswCQYDVQQGEwJE
RTEPMA0GA1UECBMGQnJlbWVuMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZCcmVtZW4xETAPBgNVBAoTCFNp
Z25hbGlzMRowGAYDVQQLExF1Z2QtYnJicmVmLXNlcnYtNzEaMBgGA1UEAxMRdWdk
LWJyYnJlZi1zZXJ2LTcwHhcNMTQwOTIzMDkxOTA1WhcNMTUwOTIzMDkxOTA1WjB6
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEPMA0GA1UECBMGQnJlbWVuMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZCcmVtZW4x
ETAPBgNVBAoTCFNpZ25hbGlzMRowGAYDVQQLExF1Z2QtYnJicmVmLXNlcnYtNzEa
MBgGA1UEAxMRdWdkLWJyYnJlZi1zZXJ2LTcwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0A
MIGJAoGBAIxLY7onLN91UPIUesdwQxvbSSqFPnYXz5HnSaZx3dkqje+g6qOupqU7
4NP4dFgLbxMx6eqKkGAVVXQ7QEn/Ekp1w6Xncts2LM9FyFHUikBDZewwyvRGbIak
WW3vexpS8FMwmESPnJ+Bk1tHd2YJ0POWGt4FQfZ1u5FR4BQk72CJAgMBAAEwDQYJ
KoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEABk5Je4aoPuv1J06Vget40vHqs+rahSpoto39Flbp2JYz
y1UQPnp6o6alLtiOQcFI0iea0zXm8LMybkZTnvP7jj2//49KOmI0+RJx6cWj+cXi
qWJbK+C+8GcU+jJYwOwJrQgEl0Lr21ExebO5Is8kqQVdSiroT5KQsdPCCjKPqYc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=DE/ST=Bremen/L=Bremen/O=Signalis/OU=localhost/CN=localhost
issuer=/C=DE/ST=Bremen/L=Bremen/O=Signalis/OU=localhost/CN=localhost
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=DE/ST=Bremen/L=Bremen/O=Signalis/OU=localhost/CN=localhost
/C=DE/ST=Bremen/L=Bremen/O=Signalis/OU=ugd-brbref-serv-7/CN=ugd-brbref-serv-7
---
SSL handshake has read 1420 bytes and written 170 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Session-ID: 542421BD481B93286D41F5BCB96272B668500E2D35C74862189BFEAF1FC4EE4C
Session-ID-ctx:
Master-Key:    
ED17146FE586DE1A7F9E7272E1771293E964F242BF2187DF5329FFF0E3090C9B14B298CAFD13558A8F763444E6A53B5A
Key-Arg   : None
Krb5 Principal: None
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
Start Time: 1411654077
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

So the error message in openssl is

```
SSL alert number 42
```

The error message in the Jboss logging is:

```
2014-09-25 11:38:34,366 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint] (http-0.0.0.0-8765-1) Handshake failed
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:231)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate(ServerHandshaker.java:1369)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:160)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.handshake(JSSESocketFactory.java:160)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.setSocketOptions(JIoEndpoint.java:633)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

So the error message in Jboss is

```
null cert chain
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Am I doing it right in principle? First generating a certificate in a keystore, then exporting it and importing it into a truststore. Does anybody has some experience with client authentication in Jboss 5.1 GA? Maybe I'm using openssl in a wrong way to test the client authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the openssl command, you need to export your private key and then execute the command as follows:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8765 -CAfile test.cert -cert test.cert -key MYKEY.key
```

See the docs on [s_client(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) and [s_server(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_server.html) for details.

Comment: This one works, thanks a lot! But I'm kind of confused now. Why does the client need the private key for the client authentication? I thought, i just have to give the public keys to the clients, one public key for each client. I'm trying to make a rest web-service, which can only be called via client-authentication...

Comment: @Reckert Take a look in this link [An Introduction to Mutual SSL Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication)

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I need to export the private key together with the certificate in p12 format for the client authentication. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Reckert You can use this application to manage keystores [http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/)